# How do I get this code to print one single object and not three?

Tags: python

I would like to get help with this code, it's python.

```
import random
materials=['metal','paper','water']
for value in materials:
    random.shuffle(materials)
print materials[0]
```

Comment: If you indent it correctly it does only print one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly. You may have an indentation error.
Try

```
import random
materials=['metal','paper','water']
for value in materials:
    random.shuffle(materials)
print materials[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement is unnecessary, if you use only.`random.shuffle` is sufficient. Use this:

```
import random
materials=['metal','paper','water']
random.shuffle(materials)

print materials[0]
```

If you want *only* a value use choice:

```
import random
materials=['metal','paper','water']

print random.choice(materials)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `print materials[0]` will print the first element of the list, so that will output whichever string is first after the shuffle.

Your code, if formatted correctly will shuffle your list 3 times, and then print whatever is the first item following the shuffles.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one to print single word

```
import random

materials = ['metal','paper','water']

random.shuffle(materials)

print (materials[0])
```

and this one for whole string

```
import random

materials = ['metal','paper','water']

random.shuffle(materials)

print (materials)
```